# Emulate Celery rate-limitting with CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER set?

Tags: python, unit-testing, celery

When unit testing, I have `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` set to `True`, causing tasks to be executed locally instead of being sent to the queue.

However, **I need to rate limit task execution when testing and I'd like recommendations on how to do this.**

The reason for wanting to rate-limit (ideally it mirrors the project's celery config regarding limits) is because I am connecting to a rate-limited service and want to ensure my tasks don't exceed said limit for 2 reasons:

- as a test of the rate-limit
- and to be able to use the rate-limited service in other unit tests

If the 2nd point seems like bad practice because the service could be down when running tests, thus giving misleading results, I could appreciate suggestions on avoiding that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend mocking the external service. You can implement rate limiting in your mock code.

[This](http://www.appneta.com/blog/python-unit-test-mock/) seems like a good tutorial on this approach.